# Flutter app is not running after installing it in my physical device

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I built an weather app in flutter, but after installing it in my physical mobile it shows me an exception like:

> "No address associated with hostname",

but it is working perfectly fine in my simulator.

[image]

Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add internet permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```